# Hibernate : MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column ' ____ ' in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to Hibernate.

I want to fetch all records from Transaction table,

I got following error

```
 Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column transactio2_.deleted' in 'field list'
```

Though `deleted` column in present in Table

**Entity Class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction implements Comparable<Transaction>
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "transactionId")
private int transactionId;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@Column(name = "amount")
private BigDecimal amount;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "transactionTypeId")
private TransactionType transactionType;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;

@Column(name = "operation")
private String operation;

@Column(name = "lastUpdate")
private Date lastUpdate;

@Column(name = "deleted")
private int deleted;

@Column(name = "remark")
private String remark;

public Transaction()
{
    super();
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Transaction c)
{
    if (getTransactionId() < c.getTransactionId())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (getTransactionId() > c.getTransactionId())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

public Date getLastUpdate()
{
    return lastUpdate;
}

public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate)
{
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
}

public User getUser()
{
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user)
{
    this.user = user;
}

public int getDeleted()
{
    return deleted;
}

public void setDeleted(int deleted)
{
    this.deleted = deleted;
}

public int getTransactionId()
{
    return transactionId;
}

public void setTransactionId(int transactionId)
{
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
}

public Date getDate()
{
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date)
{
    this.date = date;
}

public BigDecimal getAmount()
{
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount)
{
    this.amount = amount;
}

public TransactionType getTransactionType()
{
    return transactionType;
}

public void setTransactionType(TransactionType transactionType)
{
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
}

public String getOperation()
{
    return operation;
}

public String getRemark()
{
    return remark;
}

public void setRemark(String remark)
{
    this.remark = remark;
}

public void setOperation(String operation)
{
    this.operation = operation;
}
 }
```

**Hibernate transactionBean :**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TransactionBean implements Serializable
{

    ArrayList<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
   * Public Constructor
    */
public TransactionBean()
{
     Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    transactionList = (ArrayList<Transaction>) session.createCriteria(Transaction.class).list();     
}
```

What goes wrong in my code ?

**Edit : Here is create statement of DB Table**

```
 delimiter $$

   CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
      `transactionId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `transactionTypeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `operation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `lastUpdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `remark` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`transactionId`),
        KEY `fk_transaction_1` (`userId`),
        KEY `fk_transaction_2` (`transactionTypeId`),
        CONSTRAINT `fk_transaction_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`userId`) ON     DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
       CONSTRAINT `fk_transaction_2` FOREIGN KEY (`transactionTypeId`) REFERENCES   `transaction_type` (`transactionTypeId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Comment: add your table creation script to verify db column name with hibernate mapping

Comment: May be you spell wrong column name in db, first check that

Comment: change `deleted` column datatype from `tinyint` to `int` same as `transactionId` column and your issue resolve

Comment: I used tinyint because i am going to set value, only Zero(0) OR one(1)

Comment: then try `boolean` in mapping. with one more change `tinyint(1)` if you just need 0 or 1

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue if I manually create JPA Entities.
Just make sure you have **@Column** annotation for each getter function.

```
@Column(name = "deleted")
public int getDeleted()
{
    return deleted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using 0 or 1 in `tinyint` column use below mapping it will works.

```
@Column(name = "deleted")
private boolean deleted;
```

and one more change if you need to try,
you are using boolean value `0,1` so you can use `tinyint(1)`, which is enought for 0,1.

you can find more about hibernate mapping [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_types.htm)

Comment: with 

@Column(name = "deleted")

private int deleted;
mapping and 
tinyint(4),
when i insert data, data is inserted fine (it will not give any ERROR while insertion)

Comment: In 'TransactionType' (which is ManyToOne in 'Transaction') entity i missed deleted column. That's why it is giving ERROR, But Hibernate gives ERROR "Unknown column transactio2_.deleted' in 'field list'", that's why i got confused, it should give ERROR  Like  " Unknown column 'tarnsactionType.deleted' in 'field list'"

@ jubinPatel : thanx for your time

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issue recently. In my case it was missing database column